# I joined multiple images into a rope. How can I decrease the rope stretchiness?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, verlet-integration, elasticity

I created a rope based off [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82022/create-game-like-cut-the-rope-using-sprite-kit-swift) tutorial, except my rope has one ball attached on each end of the rope.

High Level: This is how they create the rope.

1. create an array of `SKNodes`
2. append each rope segment (node) to the array
3. add each node to the screen
4. join each node together to form a rope
5. (Then I add a ball on each end of the rope)

In my program I move the ball around and basically swing the rope around kind of like a stretchy pendulum.

**Here's my issue:** If I swing the rope around very hard, the rope stretches too much! How can I decrease the amount the rope stretches? I don't see a method to decrease the elasticity of the body.

If there is any other information that will be useful please let me know! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can try these two methods. The first method is to increase the property `frictionTorque` of `SKPhysicsJointPin` class.

> The range of values is from 0.0 to 1.0. The default value is 0.0. If a
>   value greater than the default is specified, friction is applied to
>   reduce the object’s angular velocity around the pin.

An example for the tutorial you followed, before adding a `joint` to the scene, modify `frictionTorque`:

```
for i in 1...length {
    let nodeA = ropeSegments[i - 1]
    let nodeB = ropeSegments[i]
    let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.jointWithBodyA(nodeA.physicsBody!, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody!,
        anchor: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(nodeA.frame), CGRectGetMinY(nodeA.frame)))
    joint.frictionTorque = 0.5    // Add this line

    scene.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
}
```

The second method is to limit the swing angle of the pin joint. After enabling `shouldEnableLimits`, adjust `lowerAngleLimit` and `upperAngleLimit` in radians.

Read more about SKPhysicsJointPin Class Reference for [Determining the Characteristics of the Pin Joint](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJointPin_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013036-CH1-SW7).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried changing the `frictionTorque`, turning on `shouldEnableLimits` and adjusting the upper/lower limits. Nothing changed, any other ideas?

Comment: I was able to figure it out! Changing the density of the rope was able to solve the stretching issue